# Cannot export org file into html. Error: make-htmlize-fstruct: Symbol’s function definition is void: record

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

For some reason I cannot export certain org-mode files to html. Org-files without headers work fine. However, if I have a file with

```
#+TITLE: This is the title of my website
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
#+OPTIONS: toc:t tex:t default TOC
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
This is my personal website.
```

I get the following error message `make-htmlize-fstruct: Symbol’s function definition is void: record`,
and this is the debugger result.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function record)
  record(htmlize-fstruct "#e1e1e0" "#2d3743" nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
  make-htmlize-fstruct(:foreground "#e1e1e0" :background "#2d3743")
  htmlize-face-to-fstruct-1(default)
  htmlize-face-to-fstruct(default)
  htmlize-make-face-map((default underline font-lock-variable-name-face font-lock-string-face font-lock-type-face matlab-cellbreak-face font-lock-keyword-face font-lock-constant-face font-lock-comment-face))
  htmlize-buffer-1()
  htmlize-region(1 3566)
  org-html-htmlize-region-for-paste(1 3566)
  org-export-as(html nil nil nil (:output-file "index.html"))
  org-export-to-file(html "index.html" nil nil nil nil nil)
  org-html-export-to-html(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Note that I had to remove some portion in the middle of the output, because it was very long and it had non-ASCII characters. I was able to found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize/issues/17) but don't know how they solved it. My emacs version is 25.2.2 and org-mode is v9.2. I am on a Linux Mint 19.1 machine.

Comment: `record` was added in Emacs 26.1, maybe your htmlize.el is compiled with Emacs 26.1? if that's true, you can try to recompile htlmize.el with your current version of Emacs to fix the issue.

Comment: Previously I was using emacs 27 from the emacs-snapshot repository. Since the downgrade to 25, and In order to avoid issues, I have deleted and reinstalled most of my packages with melpa. Can you tell me how should I proceed to recompile htmlize.el then? Thanks

Comment: I use `(setq package-user-dir (concat "~/.emacs.d/elpa-" emacs-version))` to avoid sharing packages across different versions of Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using melpa requires that `M-x package-reinstall` RET and then type `htmlize`. Thanks xuchunyang